# NullReferenceException in Global.asax when referencing Context.User.Identity in Session_Start

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

When I am debugging an application in ASP.NET, after about ~5 minutes I get a NullRefEx coming from global.asax.cs regarding:

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowsIdentity identity = null;
            identity = (WindowsIdentity)(Context.User.Identity);
...
```

Context is Null at this point.  I am a noob in ASP.NET with regards to Global.asax.cs.  This code was written by another developer.

EDIT:
This is the code with HttpContext...

```
    protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    WindowsIdentity identity = null;
    identity = (WindowsIdentity)(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
```

Comment: If this is time dependent, have you checked to see if the app pool is recycling?

Comment: I think you are on the right track. I am using visual studio's builtin asp.net developer debugging thing ( no idea what its officially called). Is it possible to set the recycle time of this debugger tool?

Comment: This is IIS 5.1. I don't think there's a recycle option as there's no named app pools.  Also checked the Application Configuration options and session state is enabled with a timeout of 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
identity = (WindowsIdentity)(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
```

edited to be more clear (I hope...)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the difference here please?

Comment: UPDATE:  The problem still exists with HttpContext.

Comment: I just tried it on my site and it works for me. Can you post your revised code? I will edit my answer to more clearly show what I meant.

Comment: I added the updated code.  Its practically identical.  The problem ONLY occurs after about ~5 minutes.  There is no issue at startup.

Comment: Weird. So in your first (startup) session, it works. But then after 5 minutes or so, you start a new session and it fails? Is it HttpContext.Current that is null at this point? Or could it be something else?

Comment: Yes thats what's happening.  I don't know why i'm starting a new session so early either.  HttpContext is null at this point, it could be something higher up the chain, but I am not sure.

Comment: The new session is probably caused by your timeout value of 1. Is this new session another page request from the same browser, or is it a new browser window, or something else entirely? Is there anything in the call stack that might be helpful?

Comment: I'm giving up on this for now. This application was built in visual studio 2000, problems started in the conversion to 2008. Solution is no solution.